# Can't get new router working on existing network

Tags: networking, router

I have a network of however-many machines hooked up directly to a switch. It's cro-magnon hardware, so the wireless aspect is controlled by a box, which I suspect has no software, IP, etc of its own, connected to that switch.

I have a few more computers hooked up to a Netgear R4500, which is simple enough to use and seems to work within its own network and on the internet. The computers are hooked up to the Netgear, which is in turn hooked up to the switch through one port.

I cannot integrate the computers hooked up to the Netgear with the ones directly hooked up to the switch. I want the Netgear simply to function as a wireless access and a couple extra Cat5 ports, and require the DHCP server that was already there without acting as one itself.

The default gateway on the main network and on the Netgear are both set to 192.168.3.243, which is an Ubuntu desktop. The internet works for both switch computers and Netgear computers.

When I run traceroute from a Macbook hooked up to the switch:

```
traceroute to 192.168.3.243 (192.168.3.243), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
1  192.168.3.243 (192.168.3.243)  6.104 ms  1.223 ms  1.239 ms
```

When I run traceroute from a Macbook hooked up to Netgear:

```
 traceroute to 192.168.3.243 (192.168.3.243), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1)  0.722 ms  0.802 ms  0.365 ms
 2  192.168.3.243 (192.168.3.243)  1.664 ms  0.660 ms  0.781 ms
```

Furthermore, the Netgear continues to function as DHCP.

The Netgear claims its "internet IP" is 192.168.3.89 (proving it is hooked up to the switch and not doing what I want it to) with default gateway 192.168.3.243. What this means is that the Netgear thinks that the local network is the internet and that 192.168.3.243 is the ISP. As a result, computers hooked up to the Netgear can connect to the rest of the network but not vice versa.

How do I make it do what I want?

Comment: UPDATE: Internet functionality on the Netgear broke while I was typing, had to post from a computer connected to the old wireless. Also, can't ping 192.168.3.89 from other computers.

Comment: I guess it isn't clear: I already turned off DHCP on the netgear and it's doing it anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want the Netgear to function as a WAP with a bridged connection for the ethernet ports. I'm not familiar with that model, but essentially you just need to disable DHCP and make sure that your router and all computers are on the same subnet. The gateway is going to be the last stop in the network before you egress to the internet. It sounds like you also want this to be your DHCP server. The other thing to be aware of is that a switch is a layer 2 device, meaning it's only going to work off of a MAC address table and will not be involved in routing at all.

All that said, try the following:

1. Turn off DHCP on  your Netgear (it may have an "Access Point" mode like some models which achieves the same thing.)
2. Go to whatever device is handling your routing and DHCP (assuming they're the same device) and make sure your subnet and DHCP pool are correct.
3. Make sure that all devices on your network are pulling an address from DHCP so that there is no risk of putting them in the wrong subnet.

Once you have all of that done, the Netgear should be a pass-through and all of your devices should automatically be pointing to the router and pulling their addresses from its DHCP server.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the Netgear thinks it's controlling everything on the network, giving out IP addresses and acting as a gateway. It needs to be (pseudo) configured as an access point.

To sort this out, do the following:

- Connect your machine directly into one of the Netgear LAN ports, unplug everything other network cable from the Netgear, including from the WAN port.
- Determine the network range of your internal network (looks like 192.168.1.0/24)
- Give the Netgear LAN interface an address on that network that is outside the DHCP range of the router that is handing out DHCP, if you don't know what that is then something high up like 192.168.1.221 is probably going to be safe.
- Once it reboots, turn **off** DHCP on the R4500.
- Plug one of the LAN ports into the existing switch
- Reboot the existing switch
- Do a happy dance because your AP should now work as you want it to

Note that you should no longer use the WAN port of the Netgear, cover it in tape or something so you know not to use it. The other ports (3?) can be used for PCs.

Note that sometimes the bridging does not work, this is rare and usually only seen with very old switches, however this setup will work in 99.9% of cases.

Comment: @kelario yes, edited to clarify.

Comment: 192.168.3.0/24 is the main network range. 3.221 is in use, trying 3.210

Comment: Google "Angry IP Scanner" and use it to scan your network from 192.168.3.1 to 192.168.3.254, you should see where most the computers are and choose an IP well away from them. Even better, find out what the DHCP range is from the other device that hands them out :-)

Comment: Googling it. I moved the WAN cord to a LAN port, which now has an amber light on the front. Can no longer ping 192.168.3.243 ("host is down"), and Attached Devices gives the only attached computer a hostname of --

Comment: @kelario is dhcp turned off on the Netgear? You'll need to release and renew the IP address on your PC also to get a new IP on the right range. Also try pinging the new Netgear IP.

Comment: Took AIPS from the Netgear-connected computer, changed IP range from 192.168.0.0-192.168.255.255 to 192.168.3.0-192.168.3.255. Came up with only two machines - 192.168.3.87 (the wireless IP I set manually in the computer's settings) and 192.168.3.210.

Comment: On a non-Netgear connected machine, it picked up everything it should have. 23 machines alive, 5 of which gave a hostname. 192.168.3.87 was found and gave the correct hostname, 192.168.3.210 was not.

Comment: Ok that's good info, so reboot the router and the switch to clear the MAC tables and test again.

Comment: Same results from AIPS.

Comment: What happens if you connect a wireless client to the Netgear, does it get an IP?

Comment: I figured out AP mode from the other answer. Everything hooked up to the existing network works and is seen by the Netgear. The only wireless client gets its proper address from DHCP and pinging the gateway works, but can't get to the internet. Traceroute goes straight to the gateway and no longer through Netgear.

Comment: Last issue appears to be a client-side error because my other testing computer is now connected as wireless and works fine.

Comment: Great. Good it's sorted.